# Auto overriding context in javascript functions

Tags: javascript, function, this

Take in consideration this code:

```
function a() {
  alert(this.variable);
}

b = new function() {
  this.variable = "abc";
  a.call(this);
}
```

Is there a way to auto override context instead of using the call method?
like this (not working):

```
function a() {
  var _this = Function.caller;  
  alert(_this.variable);
}

b = new function() {
  this.variable = "abc;
  a();
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If you want `a` to have access to `b`'s `this`, you'll have to pass `this` explicitly, i.e. instead of `a()` do `a(this)`.

Comment: Javascripts libraries often provide a way of doing this for you, eg Prototype.js has 'bind'. But in every case it must be done by the calling code: the function itself may be called in different ways and does not have privileged access to the context from which it was called.

Comment: passing this to a function is not a good solution, in my first example i was using the call method to ovveride the context in function a, what i want is to auto ovverride context by looking at the caller function context.

Comment: @user - you'll probably want to use a different language then.

Comment: Are you joking? or i don't understand your resplies. I think you haven't understood my first question.